# Why flash games are so slow on my RCA tablet

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, tablet

I have what is probably a very basic question about tablets. I am using an RCA 11 Maven Pro.

I'd like to understand why online flash games are so slow on this device. For example, games like Monster's Den and Amorphous on Kongregate are extremely choppy and impossible to play, yet flash animations run smoothly for gifs and videos and it has enough processing power to play 3D mobile games I've downloaded.

I've tried a litany of Google querries within and external to stack exchange without any relevant answers to this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: because it's Adobe Flash on Android

Most apps and websites are shown in the Web browser. This is a native app with lots of optimisation and hardware acceleration. This makes it possible to load large websites on your phone. The same is true for games: all game code exists when the app is installed on your device. This way, the code can be executed way more efficiently.

Flash doesn't have any hardware support or optimisations within games.

The lack of good hardware support comes from the fact that the last version was developed for Android 4.0.4 several years ago and then was abandoned. All new technologies to speed up Android that have been developed since Flash support was dropped are not available to Flash.

The lack of optimisation comes from the way flash loads game files. Every file you load in flash contains different code, animations and sounds. Flash does not precompile (process the code before it's executed) like Android does with normal games. This is another reason why flash is so slow.

Flash is a bit of a resource hog as well. From what I can find your tablet out has 1GB of RAM. This should be enough to play most simple Android games and show some websites, but it might choke on larger Flash files.

Because Adobe no longer maintains it,  Flash is also a security vulnerability. No security updates will ever come for flash on Android.

Flash is slow on even the fastest Android devices. There's no way this will ever change because Adobe doesn't bring out new versions. I'm afraid there's nothing you can do about it except closing all apps and tabs in the background and hoping for the best.